# C# How do I use AOP for static methods?

Tags: c#, .net, aop

I have built a c# .net 4.0 library.

all of the methods are public and static.

i want to add an aspect using an aspect programming library that does something like this:

```
try block
1. call method (if method throws exception)

catch block
2. log the exception and massage the exception

it is a dll (class library project)
```

can you please advice if there is a way to add try/catch routines in one class instead of wrapping around all methods one by one?

Comment: i have not implemented anything yet but i looked at few libraries for it. ive looked at ninject, castle windsor and spring.net briefly but i am not sure if it is possible to do what i want for static methods in a class library?

Comment: "all of the methods are public and static" -- sniff, sniff.  Code smell...

Comment: I don't understand why this was closed. Seems like a legit question to me.

Comment: @DStanley By itself that could simply be a functional style library. The exception plan seems far more weird.

Comment: it will be consumed by managedXll which requires all of the methods to be public static.  the reason for having a catch block is because i have to take the exception and send it back via managedxll as a resizable array, also the exception has to be logged by making an api call to another application so instead of repeating it for every method, i wanted to introduce it in AOP

Answer (score 5):

Because you had mentioned word `static` neither [ninject](/questions/tagged/ninject) nor [castle-windsor](/questions/tagged/castle-windsor) nor anything else based upon [castle-dynamicproxy](/questions/tagged/castle-dynamicproxy) would help you, because they able to add aspects around regular method. So you have two options:

## Handwritten tracing decorator

Add separate handwritten tracing decorator that will add required functionality without altering of existing code

- Benefits

  - Simple and easy to write yourself
- Drawbacks

  - **Almost no call context**. This is important for tracing, if you like to know what method actually has been called and what parameters had been passed, etc.
  - **New layer of abstraction around existed code**. Instead of calling your static methods, you *have to* call Decorator that will call your static methods inside

### Example

```
// Decorated calls
TraceDecorator.Aspect(() => StaticLogic.SuccessfulCall());
TraceDecorator.Aspect(() => StaticLogic.ExceptionCall());
TraceDecorator.Aspect(() => StaticLogic.SuccessfulCallWithReturn(42));
TraceDecorator.Aspect(() => StaticLogic.ExceptionCallWithReturn(42));

// Decorator itself
public static class TraceDecorator
{
    public static T Aspect<T>(Func<T> func)
    {
        try
        {
            return func();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            LogException(ex);

            return default(T);
        }    
    }

    public static void Aspect(Action func)
    {
        try
        {
            func();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            LogException(ex);
        }    
    }

    private static void LogException(Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Traced by TraceDecorator: {0}", ex);
    }
}
```

Full sample available [here](https://gist.github.com/4457261)

## PostSharp

Take a look at [Non-Invasive Tracing & Logging](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/solutions/logging) with [postsharp](/questions/tagged/postsharp)

- Benefits

  - Broadcast your aspect without altering existing code or adding attributes by yourself, whatever you found suitable
  - **Separation of concerns**: tracing/logging are separated from your logic
  - and alot more …
- Drawbacks

  - Nothing come for free. But there is a free PostSharp edition available with limited functionality
  - Sometimes integration with other tools because of post-compilation

Answer (score 0):

See [NConcern .NET AOP Framework](http://aspectize.codeplex.com), an open source project.

**Example**

Your static class

```
static public class Calculator
{
    static public int Add(int a, int b)
    {
        return a + b;
    }
}
```

Logger

```
static public class Logger
{
    static public void Log(MethodInfo method, object[] arguments, Exception exception)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}({1}) exception = {2}", method.Name, string.Join(", ", arguments), exception.Message);
    }
}
```

Aspect : log on exception

```
public class Logging : IAspect
{
    public IEnumerable<IAdvice> Advise(MethodInfo method)
    {
        yield return Advice.Basic.After.Throwing((instance, arguments, exception) => 
        {
            Logger.Log(method, arguments, exception);
        });
    }
}
```

Joinpoint : methods of Calculator

```
var calculatorMethods = new Func<MethodInfo, bool>(method => method.ReflectedType == typeof(Calculator));
```

Activate the logging aspect for joinpoint

```
Aspect.Weave<Logging>(calculatorMethods);
```